# Can lead produce an electromagnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity

I know that if you put an electromagnet in front of a copper coil it will induce a magnetic field into the copper coil but will it do the same to lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lead can conduct electricity  (all metals can), it conducts electricity at 7% of the conductivity of copper. So I can't see why not, although it will be a very weak field.

Below is a list of conductivities relative to copper

1 Silver (Pure) 105%

2 Copper 100%

3 Gold (Pure) 70%

4 Aluminum 61%

5 Brass 28%

6 Zinc 27%

7 Nickel 22%

8 Iron (Pure) 17%

9 Tin 15%

10 Phosphor Bronze 15%

11 Steel (Stainless included) 3-15%

12 Lead (Pure) 7%

- Conductivity ratings are expressed as a relative measurement to copper. A 100% rating does not indicate no resistance.

As you can see the differences in electrical conductivity vary considerably depending on the metal.